# Cucumber Feature Failing Selecting Option

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, capybara

Can't figure out why this feature won't pass...I know it's working from manual testing, but I'm continually getting this error

```
cannot select option, no option with text 'Don Moen' in select box 'audio_file[artist_id]'
(Capybara::ElementNotFound)
(eval):2:in `select'
./features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:34:in `/^I select "(.*?)" from "(.*?)"$/'
features/adding_audio.feature:19:in `When I select "Don Moen" from "audio_file[artist_id]"'
```

Scenario failing:

```
Background:
    Given I am on the home page
    And I have an admin account
    And I submit valid login information
    And I am in the admin panel
    And I follow "New Upload"

Scenario: Adding Audio with Existing Artist
    Given the following Artists exist
        |   name     |
        |   Don Moen |
    When I fill in "Title" with "Song Name"
    When I select "Don Moen" from "audio_file[artist_id]"
    And I press "Upload"
    Then I should not see an error message
```

Problem step definitions:

```
Given /^the following Artists exist$/ do |table|
  table.hashes.each do |attributes|
    Artist.create :name => attributes[:name]
  end
end

When /^I select "(.*?)" from "(.*?)"$/ do |option, field|
  page.select option, :from => field
end
```

I know the problem has something to do with the model not saving in the database, because if I manually add that artist in the test console, the feature passes.

Maybe some db configuration I have screwed up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't tell at which point you actually visit the page, but I suspect you're doing before before the artist records are created, therefore the dropdown will be empty.

Comment: Exactly right, I was visiting the page in my Background. It's okay, I'm a noob ;). Thanks a lot.